# Samsung French door refrigerator keeps freezing up and blocking the fan!

Tags: refrigerator, freezing, ice

My Samsung French door fridge’s coils keep freezing up blocking the fan from turning. I have tried everything suggested by YOUTUBERS from forced defrost, complete defrost (by unplugging the fridge for 24 hrs.) to replacing the metal part at the bottom of the heater coil, that goes in the drain hole, with a longer one, from Amazon, that goes deeper into the hole.

I also tried to change the location of the sensor on the coil as well as sealing around the back panel cover with aluminum tape to prevent any warm air from getting behind the back cover. Trying forced defrost and complete defrost seems to work fine for a few days and then the cooling fan starts to get noisy again from hitting the ice until it stops completely because it becomes blocked by the ice buildup.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!! The heating element gets hot when in the forced defrost mode and, from what I read, that means the thermistor is working. Thanks!!
The model number for the fridge is :RF23HCEDBSR/AA

Comment: Have you checked the drain tube is open all the way?  Make sure all the water can drain out.  Either that or the sensor/timer unit is defective.

Comment: Yes the drain tube is open and the water is draining ok. Sometimes when the freezing problem happens, the drain outlet will be frozen as well and I have to melt the ice to open it.

Comment: Crip659: are you talking about the defrost temperature sensor or the thermistor being defective?

Comment: The defrost sensor.  The thermistor seems to work on manual, but not automatic.

Comment: Check for air infiltration, e.g. a leaky door gasket, or a fridge tilted to the front. Increase the leg height in front to tilt the unit slightly backwards, so that gravity keeps the door closed.

Comment: Try the currency bill test. Place the bill every few inches around the door so the door gasket holds it in place, if not the door gasket needs replacement. You might check the warrenty.

Comment: I replaced the defrost sensor that looks like a probe mounted onto the evaporator pipe with a new one I bought from eBay. A few days later, the same issue occurred. Any other suggestions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is almost 2 years old, no one has suggested that it could have a coolant leak and is low on coolant.  Icing on the evaporator coils is a common indication that there is a coolant leak.